# Django marshmallow validate error message not translating

Tags: django, marshmallow

I have defined a shema in django project.

```
gross_weight = fields.Decimal(required=True, validate=validate.Range(min=0, max=9999.99, error=translation.ugettext(INVALID_RANGE_DURATION).format("0", "9999.99")))
```

Here the error message is not getting translated

But the same thing is getting translated when i call in pre_load or post load functions.

My guess is that the format is putting value first and then the translation is happening.

.po file

```
msgid "Value must be between {} and {}"
msgstr "आज भारी बारिश का पूर्वानुमान{}  है {}"
```

Comment: Yeah, I suppose in this case ugettext is called at import time while in the pre/post load case it is called at runtime (should be easy to confirm by wrapping it in a function with a print).I don't have a simple solution to this but I'm interested in what other users have come up with.